# Is it ok if you subvert expectation by completely resetting the story beat?

Tags: creative-writing, plot, story

Let's say that character beats follow a certain narrative like marry the girl of his dreams, then the girl of his dreams dies mid-way in the story beats series, and you do a 180 turn and start a new story beat where the ultimate goal is to avenge the death of your girl and kill a man.  Is it ok to do that or is this some kind of anti-pattern that should be avoided? Why?

Comment: Stories of the type you're describing often have a prologue with a scene from after the turn in the plot, so the reader doesn't rebel when (to use your example) the romance story you've been promising suddenly turns into a revenge thriller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine as long as it works.

The difficulties with its working lie in the way readers are twisted mid-story to a new plot.  They may not enjoy the new plot.  They may not enjoy it even if they would have enjoyed the story on its own.

The only real way to test it is to try out the story on beta readers.